Business Card codelab layout
I am on this part of the android dev course:
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-business-card?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-1-pathway-3%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-business-card#1
We are suppose to build a business card with an Icon in the center, and use a combo of row and col to make it.
The below code is what I have so far, I can't figure out how to make ComposeNameTile bit center, and the ComposeEmailSocialPhone land on the bottom.
It renders like this:

and we are aiming for this:

I did find a bit of a cheat in that if I just make two Rows they would overlap each other, then make one row center vertically and the other row align bottom, I could get something similar to what the goal wants, but I think that would be a bad design right? since if the screen changes it would look all wrong?
I found a similar question to this but I am trying to understand how row and col play so I don't want to touch Constrained/Box stuff yet.
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            BusinessCardTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
                ) {
                    ComposeMainInfo()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ComposeMainInfo() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color(0xFFB69DF8)),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color(0xFFEADDFF)),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        ) {
            ComposeNameTitle()
        }
        Spacer(Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color(0xFFD0BCFF)),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
        ) {
            ComposeEmailSocialPhone()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ComposeEmailSocialPhone() {
    ComposeMainInfoTexts(name = "+1 564565165474")
    ComposeMainInfoTexts(name = "@facebook")
    ComposeMainInfoTexts(name = "jrfdfdasdfsdfasfy@gmail.com")
}

@Composable
fun ComposeNameTitle() {
    val MyAppIcons = Icons.Rounded
    ComposeMainInfoLogo(icon = MyAppIcons.Menu)
    ComposeMainInfoTexts(name = "samel  \n davis")
    ComposeMainInfoTexts(name = "Software Engineer")
}

@Composable
fun ComposeMainInfoTexts(name: String) {
    Text(
        text = name,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
        fontSize = 24.sp,
    )
}

@Composable
fun ComposeMainInfoLogo(icon: ImageVector) {
    Icon(Icons.Rounded.Menu, contentDescription = "Localized description")
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    BusinessCardTheme {
        ComposeMainInfo()
    }
}


First of, ComposeNameTitle and ComposeEmailSocialPhone each contain multiple composables, but they are not arranged in a layout component (such as a Column or Row). Instead, you wrap those composables in a Column where they are called. The Column is an integral part of ComposeNameTitle and ComposeEmailSocialPhone and should be moved there.
With all of that gone, ComposeMainInfo looks much cleaner now:
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(Color(0xFFB69DF8)),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
) {
    ComposeNameTitle()
    Spacer(Modifier.height(20.dp))
    ComposeEmailSocialPhone()
}

Back to the original question, how to vertically layout the content of this Column. As it is right now, you just put a spacer in between and otherwise just let one element immediately follow the next. This can be changed, however, by setting the verticalArrangement of the Column. When you set it to Arrangement.SpaceBetween the content is evenly distributed among the available space. That takes care of positioning ComposeEmailSocialPhone at the bottom.
Now, to center ComposeNameTitle you would need a third component that comes first so that ComposeNameTitle is in the middle. You could use a Spacer for that. In fact, the Spacer you already have can be used for that. It isn't needed any more to separate the other two composables, that is already taken care of by the verticalArrangement.
Putting everything together, it looks like this:
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(Color(0xFFB69DF8)),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
) {
    Spacer(Modifier.height(20.dp))
    ComposeNameTitle()
    ComposeEmailSocialPhone()
}

There are some other values verticalArrangement can be set to that might be a better fit for this. The documentation contains animated examples of each.
