How to align elements of a column in Jetpack Compose
I have a Column that contains a Description and a Contact. Description contains the full name, a title and an image, and Contact contains some contact information.
I want to put a space in between, like this:

This is my code so far:
@Composable
fun Card(name: String, role: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Description(name = name, role = role)
        Contact(modifier = Modifier)
    }
}

@Composable
fun Description(name: String, role: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val image = painterResource(R.drawable.android_logo_0)
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(
            top = 100.dp,
        ),
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = image,
            contentDescription = null,
        )
        Text(
            text = name,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold,
            fontSize = 40.sp
        )
        Text(
            text = role,
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            color = Color(0xFF155115),
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun Contact(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(
            bottom = 0.dp,
            top = 210.dp,
            start = 70.dp,
        )
    ) {
        ContactCard(name = "abc@gmail.com", icon = R.drawable.baseline_email_black_24dp, modifier = Modifier)
        ContactCard(name = "abc", icon = R.drawable.circle_linkedin_512, modifier = Modifier)
        ContactCard(name = "123456", icon = R.drawable.baseline_call_black_24dp, modifier = Modifier)
    }
}


This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78277511/business-card-codelab-layout. Does that answer your question?

your answer to that question there solved my problem.thnks!

You can do these 2 things. 

You can add Spacer tag and give height as a parameter like this:
 Spacer(Modifier.height(20.dp))




2. You can add this parameter in the Column:
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween

If its not working try using both together
